# How to make an interactive Dijkstra/Kruskal graph in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, dijkstra, kruskals-algorithm

I'm creating a Dijkstra implementation in WPF and I want the user to be able to create their own graph by dragging and dropping nodes onto a canvas, then adding edges/arcs to those nodes (ellipses) - these will later be read from the canvas to create a graph to solve.

I have no idea where to start and my searches haven't turned up anything useful. I'm mainly confused about how to drag and drop ellipses in a canvas, how to create edges that bind to the position of the nodes, and whether I can use linq on Canvas.Items to get all the nodes and edges from the graph.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i found a sample online https://github.com/marclitchfield/DijkstraSolver , i asolutely take NO credits for the demo. Those credit go out to https://github.com/marclitchfield

I only take credit for search on google for this. You can connect with git to this repo, open the solution in Visual Studio and run. It is written in VB.NET, but maybe you can get some hints on how to get you starting

Double clicking a node will create a new node, and with drag drop you can drag nodes around. Right click on the canvas gives you save and load options